# Cannot remove duplicates from range

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel table with several columns two of which I am interested in. What I am trying to do is filter the first column with a specific criterion and then copy the visible values from the other column into a range object. After that I need to remove duplicates. The problem is I get an error. Here's the code. There are a lot of duplicates. Please tell me what's wrong or suggest a better way to achieve the task I'm trying to do.

```
Sub Begin()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

WorkSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="DUKESTREET_II-2"

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 =  tbl.ListColumns("TGT CELL NAME").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
MsgBox rng1.Count
rng1.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
MsgBox rng1.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? `WorkSheet.AutoFilterMode = False` This doesn't look right? Should be `Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False`

Comment: I know I just skipped that part. I actually have a definition above. Thats not the problem. I get a problem at:
rng1.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Comment: For some reason with rng1, I can't pass it to selection with rng1.select

Comment: You cannot use `.RemoveDuplicates` with multiple selections i.e non contiguous ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're off to a great start, but unfortunately as @siddharth-rout pointed out `.RemoveDuplicates` will not work on a non-contiguous range.

In this case, to collect the all the unique cell values from the "TGT CELL NAME" column, you could use a [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f26wd2e5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (MSDN link):

[image: start]

```
Sub Begin()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng1 As Range, RngIdx As Range
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim UniqueTGTCells As Collection

Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = MySheet.ListObjects("Table1")

'only turn off auto filter mode if it's already set to true
If MySheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    MySheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="DUKESTREET_II-2"

Set rng1 = tbl.ListColumns("TGT CELL NAME").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
MsgBox rng1.Count

'populate the collection object
Set UniqueTGTCells = New Collection
For Each RngIdx In rng1
    On Error Resume Next
    UniqueTGTCells.Add LCase(CStr(RngIdx.Value)), LCase(CStr(RngIdx.Value))
    On Error GoTo 0
Next RngIdx

'message the size of the collection
MsgBox UniqueTGTCells.Count

End Sub
```

Here are our message boxes:

[image: msg]

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a way to quickly set a range to this collection ??

Comment: Hey @medwatt, I'm not sure about a directly creating a range from UniqueTGTCells and unfortunately won't be able to test for at least another day. You can, however, iterate through a collection easily with a 'for each object in collection' loop

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to this old post below, in case anybody struggle again with that.
Note that I translated my working code into the posted one without testing, but I guess the idea is simple enough to be applied anyway.

```
Sub Begin()


Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

WorkSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="DUKESTREET_II-2"
' Sort to make sure filtered view will be contiguous
tbl.range.sort Key1:=tbl.range.cells(1,8), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 =  tbl.ListColumns("TGT CELL NAME").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
MsgBox rng1.Count
' Using Areas(1) does the trick (there is only 1 area - no gaps - thanks to sorting)
rng1.Areas(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
MsgBox rng1.Count

End Sub
```